# Android Studio: Unable to extract raw String text from PDF file using PDFBox

Tags: java, android-studio, exception, crash, pdfbox

I am using the PDFBox library for the first time to create an app in which I need to be able to extract raw String text from a PDF file. Whenever I run the application, it just crashes. All the methods appear to be correct however the app is still crashing.
NOTE: Android Studio shows an error in the methods unless they are within "try-catch" statements.

```
package com.example.e_reader;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.ShowText;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.util.PDFBoxResourceLoader;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button importButton = findViewById(R.id.importButton);
        final TextView pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView);

        File file = new File("C:/Users/hd009/AndroidStudioProjects/EReader/app/src/main/java/assets");
        PDDocument sample = null;
        try {
            sample = PDDocument.load(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PDFTextStripper stripper = null;
        try {
            stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String text = null;
        try {
            text = stripper.getText(sample);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pdfView.setText(text);
    }

 }
```

Comment: By *"it just crashes"* you mean what exactly? (*it just crashes* is something a user without an IT background may say. A software developer by means of logging or debugging finds out more, e.g. in which line, how exactly,...)

Comment: And share the file, so I can test it with pdfbox for desktop too.

Comment: Your pdf file is just a directory: `new File("C:/Users/hd009/AndroidStudioProjects/EReader/app/src/main/java/assets")`

Comment: @mkl I just debugged it, and the app just stops working at each of the try statements but there is nothing wrong with catch statements and anything else. It is not a syntax error. I am new to app development and coding so I am still kind of confused.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I am using just a sample PDF that I found online at this site: http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf i would appreciate it if you tested it with PDFBox. And I am also confused as to why I am required to put try catch statements.

Comment: That one extracts easily on PDFBox for desktop. I don't know if `e.printStackTrace();` works on android, IIRC one should use the logger. If the load() fails, `sample` is null, so `stripper.getText(sample)` won't work either. I also suspect you didn't understand me: your filename in your code is not a PDF file, it is a name of a directory only. (hint: PDF files usually end with ".pdf") So please fix that first. Check that your file exists.

Comment: "And I am also confused as to why I am required to put try catch statements" - this is because load() can throw an exception.

Comment: I notice that your other question now has a .pdf file in your path, so you seem to have understood my comment "Your pdf file is just a directory". What happens now?